# Inheritance and problems with the "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, this, prototypal-inheritance

I'm building a fairly complex web app that begins with a main menu where the user makes his initial selections. This is the first time I've tried a true OOP approach using inheritance in JavaScript and I've run into my first problem with the "this" keyword not referring to what I expect it to. I'm guessing that it's the result of a broader problem with my OOP/inheritance approach, so I would appreciate an answer that not only tells me how to solve this individual issue, but also provides deeper feedback and advice on my general approach.

I'm only going to post the JS code because I don't think the HTML is relevant, but I can certainly post that as well if necessary.

The following code defines the main class `Select`. It then creates a subclass of `Select` called `SelectNum` (look towards the end of the code). In `SelectNum`, I'm trying to override the `mouseover` method of `Select`, but not entirely -- I want to first call the super's (Select's) method, and then run some additional code. But when this subclass's `mouseover` method runs, I immediately get the following error:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'stop' of undefined"

Basically, `this.shine` is undefined.

To start with, I'm using the following code from O'Reilly's JavaScript: The Definitive Guide:

```
function inherit(p) {
   if (Object.create){ // If Object.create() is defined...
      return Object.create(p); // then just use it.
    }

   function f() {}; // Define a dummy constructor function.
   f.prototype = p; // Set its prototype property to p.
   return new f(); // Use f() to create an "heir" of p.
}
```

And my code:

```
Select = function(el){
    return this.init(el);
}

Select.prototype = {
    init: function(el){
        var that = this;
        this.el = el;
        this.shine = el.children('.selectShine');

        el.hover(function(){
            that.mouseover();
        },function(){
            that.mouseout();
        });

        return this;
    },
    mouseover: function(){
        this.shine.stop().animate({opacity:.35},200);
    },
    mouseout: function(){
        var that = this;
        this.shine.stop().animate({opacity:.25},200);
    }
}

//Sub-classes
SelectNum = function(el){
    this.init(el);
    this.sup = inherit(Select.prototype); //allows access to super's original methods even when overwritten in this subclass
    return this;
}

SelectNum.prototype = inherit(Select.prototype);
SelectNum.prototype.mouseover = function(){
    this.sup.mouseover(); //call super's method... but this breaks down
    //do some other stuff
}
```

**EDIT**
The response from Raynos worked. `this.sup.mouseover()` no longer threw the error, and the correct code was run. However, I actually need to create a `SelectNum` subclass called `SelectLevel`. Unlike `SelectNum` that overrides its superclass' `mouseover()` method, `SelectLevel` does NOT need to override `SelectNum`'s `mouseover()` method:

```
SelectLevel = function(el){
    this.init(el);
    this.sup = inherit(SelectNum.prototype); //allows access to super's original methods even when overwritten in this subclass
    for(var k in this.sup){
        this.sup[k] = this.sup[k].bind(this);
    }
}
SelectLevel.prototype = inherit(SelectNum.prototype);
```

With this code, the `mouseover()` method simply gets called continuously. I believe that's because `this` is now bound to the `SelectLevel` object, so `this.sup` in the line `this.sup.mouseover()` in `SelectNum` always refers to `SelectNum`, so it just keeps calling itself.

If I remove the `this.sup[k] = this.sup[k].bind(this);` binding in `SelectLevel`, then I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'mouseover' of undefined`. It appears that `this.sup.mouseover()` gets called continuously, calling the `mouseover` method on each object in the prototype chain. When it gets up to `Object`, that's when this error gets thrown because, of course, `Object` doesn't have a `sup` property.

It seems like I can solve this by removing the `this.sup[k] = this.sup[k].bind(this);` binding in `SelectLevel`, and then wrapping the `this.sup.mouseover()` in an if statement that checks first for the `sup` property before calling the `mouseover()` method on it: i.e. `if(this.sup !== undefined)`, but this really just doesn't feel right.

Ultimately, I think I'm missing something fundamental about how to subclass in JavaScript. While solutions to these particular issues do shed some light on how prototypal inheritance works in JS, I really think I need a better understanding on a broader level.

Comment: Are you sure your inherit function works?

Comment: Yes, and Raynos' answer below does solve this particular `this` issue.

Comment: Your `this.sup` is confusing. [I would recommend an alternative](http://jsfiddle.net/vE4f3/2/). It uses [pd](https://github.com/Raynos/pd)

Answer (score 2):

`this.sup.mouseover();`

calls the `.mouseover` method on the object `this.sup`. What you want is

`this.sup.mouseover.call(this)`

You don't want to call it on `this.sup` you want to call it on `this`.

If that's a pain in the ass then you can do the following in your constructor

```
this.sup = inherit(Select.prototype);
for (var k in this.sup) {
  if (typeof this.sup[k] === "function") {
    this.sup[k] = this.sup[k].bind(this);
  }
}
```

That basically means override every method with the same function but hard bind the value of `this` to what you expect/want.

Comment: Thanks. I think I prefer the second method. However, as you wrote it, it doesn't work for me. `typeof k` is always a `string` for some reason. I've currently removed that `if` statement because the prototype only has methods/functions, and it now works. But should I ever need to define properties in a prototype, then obviously the `if` statement in question would be required. So how do I keep it in there but correctly assess whether `k` is a function?

Comment: @maxedison I had a bug. it's `typeof this.sup[k]` not `typeof k`